# Write a Python program to verify the Stirling approximation

Tags: python

A very important equations in statistical mechanics is Stirling approximation for large num-bers, lnN! =NlnN−N (N >>1). Write a Python program to verify this approximation.  More specifically, evaluate the ratio lnN!/NlnN−N for N= 1000000.

Here is my program, but I can't get it to work. It doesn't give me an error, just Python breaks. I haven't been taught a lot of numpy, so I haven't been using that.

```
from math import log
N = 1000000
N_factorial=1
for i in range(1,N + 1):
       N_factorial = N_factorial*i
a = log(N_factorial)
b = N*log(N)-N
print(a/b)
```

Comment: What does "Python breaks" mean?

Comment: @khelwood It won't print anything, but won't let me run anything either. I let it sit for like 30 minutes and nothing happened, so I just restarted it and I tried to run it again and it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `math.factorial()` function:

```py
>>> import math
>>> n = 1000000
>>> math.log(math.factorial(n))/(n*math.log(n)-n)
1.0000006107204127
```

However, using the logarithm product rule, you can sum the natural log of the factors of `n` (since `log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)`, `log(a!) = log(a) + log(a-1) + log(a-2) + ... + log(2) + log(1)`)

```py
>>> import math
>>> n = 1000000
>>> sum([math.log(i+1) for i in range(n)])/(n*math.log(n)-n)
```

Comment: How long does it take if n is say, 100 times bigger?

Comment: @BobbyOcean Don't know; Have you tried it?

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong. If n was even 100 times bigger, then math.factorial(n) would have nearly 500,000,000 digits in it. The fact that this takes 7 seconds at n=1_000_000 is already a sign.

Comment: Yes, it "was" wrong, you changed your answer to my answer. This isn't a math question, this is a programming question. As a programming question, your answer "failed" (past tense) to notice the important point. Just because you are sitting at a computer that took 7 seconds is simply happen stance and not useful to programming.

Comment: @BobbyOcean My answer isn't *your* answer, as I actually *explained* why summing the logarithms is equivalent (and it doesn't include the condescending tone). My answer may have failed, but I learned (I'll thank you).

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score -3):

LOL, why is everyone posting to do this directly.

Clearly, you should be adding, not attempting to calculate a number with 6 million digits. Hence, you should have code like:

```
def logfac(n):
    return sum(math.log(i) for i in range(1,n+1))

def sterling(n):
    return n*math.log(n) − n

n = 1000000
print(logfac(n)/sterling(n))
```